# How can I unit test relative routing in Angular?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have an Angular component which contains relative routing which I would like to unit test:

```
<a [routerLink]="['..', 'NextPage']">Next Page</a>
```

The test file I have to test the component is as follows:

```
describe('ExamplePageComponent', () => {
  let component: ExamplePageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExamplePageComponent>;
  let router: Router;

  @Component({})
  class MockComponent {}

  const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'example-page/:name', component: MockComponent },
  ];

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)],
      declarations: [ ExamplePageComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
    router = TestBed.inject(Router);
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ExamplePageComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should route to next page correctly', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOnProperty(router, 'url', 'get').and.returnValue('/example-page/ThisPage');
    const navigateSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl');
    const link = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('a')
    console.log('Selected Element', link)
    link.click()
    tick(1)
    const calledUrl = navigateSpy.calls.first().args[0].toString()
    expect(calledUrl).toContain('example-page/NextPage');
  }))

});
```

However, this does not produce the expected result - instead I get the following error:

```
Error: Expected '/NextPage' to contain 'example-page/NextPage'.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/src/app/example-page/example-page.component.spec.ts:43:23)
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:1749:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:364:1)
```

I assume the issue is to do with me not correctly defining the current URL in the test file, but I'm not sure how to resolve this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking this line is not working as expected:

```
spyOnProperty(router, 'url', 'get').and.returnValue('/example-page/ThisPage');
```

Try the following:

```
it('should route to next page correctly', fakeAsync(() => {
    router.navigateByUrl('example-page/ThisPage');
    tick();
    const navigateSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigateByUrl');
    const link = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('a')
    console.log('Selected Element', link)
    link.click()
    tick(1)
    const calledUrl = navigateSpy.calls.first().args[0].toString()
    expect(calledUrl).toContain('example-page/NextPage');
  }));
```

If the above doesn't work, I would just do:

```
expect(calledUrl).toContain('NextPage');
```

It is good enough in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the response - your suggestion isn't working for me I'm afraid! And I'm tentative to use your second response as it would call a navigation to, for example, `example-page/ThisPage/NextPage` a success which isn't ideal.